# Arranging DIVs on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My webpage is divided in three columns:

```
<div id="column1"></div>
<div id="column2"></div>
<div id="column3"></div>
```

I have 3 divs:

```
<div id="1">aaa</div>
<div id="2">bbb</div>
<div id="3">ccc</div>
```

In a record in my DB i have stored the columns in which each div should be displayed:
Example: 3,1,2 (div with id 3 is displayed in column 1, id 1 in column 2, id 2 in column 3).

How can i display this divs in their correspondent columns? Without creating the divs dynamically in javascript and adding them on page load.

Comment: Why don't put them in right place serverside?

Comment: why do you want to do this in Javascript? This kind of stuff should be done when rendering the HTML on the web server, via a scripting language/framework of choice.

Comment: you should tell us how you are generating your html if you want help

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this in javascript. Just do it all on server-side while fetching DB results

Answer (score 0):

you can add all three div's in every colum div and make them hidden and on page load you can make the one you want visible. It's only a suggestion if you really want to do this in javascript